# How do I check my InnoDB settings?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Is there a MySQL command that I can execute which will show settings such as `innodb_file_format`, or a configuration file which I should check?

MySQL version: 5.5.32

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
show variables like 'innodb%';
```

Answer (score 6):

The other answers are only half correct because not all InnoDB variables start with `innodb_`. See [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html) for the full list of possible InnoDB variables your setup may have.

(Note that the manual  shows the options for the latest version in each ["release series"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/which-version.html#idm140287379715840). For example, the new [`innodb_flush_sync`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_sync) has just been added [a few days ago](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-8.html), but it is already online in the 5.7 release series manual.)

To dump them all, use:

```
show variables where variable_name in(
    'unique_checks',
    'foreign_key_checks',
    'timed_mutexes',
    'ngram_token_size',
    'mecab_rc_file'
)or variable_name like'innodb_%'
or variable_name like'%_innodb'
or variable_name like'%_innodb_%'
or variable_name like'daemon_memcached_%'
or variable_name like'%_daemon_memcached'
or variable_name like'%_daemon_memcached_%';
```

The seemingly redundant boundary checks  are included to guard against false positives when future introduction of non-InnoDB variables happens to contain the string "innodb" (e.g. "RinnoDB" or "InnoDbex").

Answer (score 2):

`show variables like 'inno%'` should show up all the innodb settings in effect at the moment you run the query.

As for files, there should probably be something like /etc/mysql/my.ini or a my.cnf somewhere.

Comment: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` Contains some MySQL information, though only a short blurb on InnoDB: `# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!` It's a starting point, though!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```

Comment: This provides some metrics regarding InnoDB, however it does not provide any information on the settings. Thanks, though.