# MYSQL insert/update slow after updating schema and loading via source

Tags: mysql

I have an j2ee web app with tomcat/mysql I'm devloping at home, I have it deployed on a home server. I spent some time upgrading it and I made some changes to the db schema.

I re-wrote the java/jsp/javascript side of it, and I then dumped the database into a text file on my local desktop, copied it to the server, and then loaded that file via the `source` command, making it the production database.

When I did that, I immediately noticed that inserts/updates were extremely slow. I had never had an issue with that in the previous version of the database.

I tried dropping the database altogether and re-creating, again using the mysql `source` command. Writes still slow.

Both the production and test versions of the db are mysql running on ubuntu.

```
test :  5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1 
server: 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

I don't know if the 16.04.1 makes a difference, but the previous version of the database had no problems.

I've done some searching, and most of the results are related to InnoDB settings. But since the previous version worked with no issues, I'm wondering it it's something obvious, like the text file importing some setting I'm not seeing.

All the tables in the mysqldump file have this at the top:

```
LOCK TABLES `address` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `address` DISABLE KEYS */;
```

Not sure if this is part of the problem? My limited understanding of table locks is it's related to a user and their current session? But again, previous versions used mysql dump files without this issue.

All the tables use smallint auto increment values for primary keys, and the db is small, most tables only have about 1000 rows and I am currently the only user.

Also, the test version of the database, which has an identical schema, runs with no problems.

Any ideas?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve by adding var in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqsld.cnf:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
```

Found a couple questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316122/mysql-very-slow-update-insert-delete-queries-hanging-on-query-end-step), re innodb settings and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977057/how-do-i-check-my-innodb-settings) for checking db settings